# Result number for Boolean queries with Apache Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

When benchmarking Apache Lucene v7.5 I noticed a strange behavior:
I indexed the English Wikipedia dump (5,677,776 docs) using Lucene with the SimpleAnalyzer (No stopwords, no stemming)

Then I searched the index with the following queries:

- **the**   totalHits=5,382,873
- **who**   totalHits=1,687,254
- **the who**   totalHits=5,411,305
- **"the who"**     totalHits=8,827

The result number for the Boolean query  ***the who***  is both larger than the result number for the single term ***the*** and the result number for the single term ***who***, when it should be smaller than both.

Is there an explanation for that?

Code snippet:

```
analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"title", "content","domain","url"},analyzer);

// Parse
Query q = parser.parse(querystr);

// top-10 results
int hitsPerPage = 10;

IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

// Ranker
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage);

// Search
searcher.search(q, collector);

// Retrieve the top-10 documents
TopDocs topDocs=collector.topDocs();

ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
totalHits=topDocs.totalHits;


System.out.println("query: "+querystr + " " + hits.length+" "+String.format("%,d",totalHits));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that [the default operator is `OR`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#setDefaultOperator-org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Operator-) and not `AND` as you assume. Searching for `the who` returns documents that have either `the` or `who` or both.

```
the - 5,382,873
who - 1,687,254
the OR who - 5,411,305
```

I.e. most documents that contain `who` also contains `the`, except for 28 432 documents which are added to the result set when you retrieve both.

You can change this behavior by changing the default operator:

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR)
```